# Problemas al reescribir el archivo con su nombre

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando hacer un programa con 'NodeJS' que pueda editar archivos online de forma colaborativa. El problema está a la hora de guardar dicho archivo, que no consigo hacer que lea el nombre.

Aquí defino en concreto la constante cData, que es lo que utiliza el resto del programa para obtener el nombre del archivo.

```
/* requerir dependencias */
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const ShareDB = require("sharedb");
const richText = require("rich-text");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const WebSocketJSONStream = require("websocket-json-stream");
const fs = require("fs");

ShareDB.types.register(richText.type);

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("static"));
app.use(express.static("node_modules/quill/dist"));

const backend = new ShareDB();
const connection = backend.connect();

const cData ={
    setData:(obj)=>{
      let da = JSON.stringify(obj);
      fs.writeFile("./cdata.json", da, function (err){
        if (err) return console.log("No funciono");
         console.log('Se ha reescrito perfectamente');
      });
    },
    getData:()=>{
      let da = fs.readFileSync("./cdata.json").toString();
      try  {
        d=JSON.parse(da);
        return d;
      } catch{
        return {};
      }
    }
}
```

Y aquí utilizo el GET para poder operar. Pero como ven, en todos me funciona correctamente (en //index y en //data) pero en //save no, ya que me da un valor 'undefined'. Es algo que no comprendo, cómo en todos los demás funciona, y en //save concretamente no.

```
/* PAGINACION */
/* index */
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var fs = require("fs");
        res.sendfile("./static/index.html");
});
app.get('/ini.js',function(req,res){
    res.send('window.cData='+JSON.stringify(cData));
});


/* data */
app.get('/data',function(req,res){
    var fs = require("fs");
    res.sendfile("./files/"+cData.fileName);
});

app.get('/rdata', function(req, res){

  let param ={
      fileName : req.query.fileName,
      time:new Date
  }
  param.contents= fs.readFileSync("./files/"+param.fileName).toString();
  res.send(JSON.stringify(param));
});

/* save */
app.get('/save',function(req,res){

    fs.writeFile("./files/"+cData.fileName, req.query.myText, function (err){
    if (err) return console.log("No funciono");
    console.log('Se ha reescrito perfectamente');
    console.log(cData.fileName);
    console.log(req.query.myText);
        });
});
```

Pd: 'fs' está como const en el primer fragmento de código, he probado a meterlo como una variable local, pero tampoco funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí inserto cómo trabaja el código en consola, y como ven, myText si que funciona, como en todas partes, pero cData.fileName decide no funcionar aquí. ¿Hay alguna explicación?

**[EDIT]**

Aquí pongo el fragmento de donde sale el valor fileName:

```
function showname () {
      /*var name = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]; 
      console.log(name.files.item(0).name);*/
    var fileName = document.getElementById("fileInput");
    var files = fileName.files;
    var file
    // loop through files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // get item
        file = files.item(i);
        //or
        file = files[i];
        return file.name;
    }
}
```

Y acabo de caer en la cuenta de que es una variable local...Pero otras funciones lo escuchan. Ahora si que estoy perdido.

Comment: También he probado con 'req.query.fileName' y tampoco funcionaba, siempre daba un valor 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he conseguido, el problema estaba en el documento html, ya que no recibía una respuesta con el `file.Name`

El problema venía de aquí:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Guardar">
```

El input `btn` activaba la función showname

```
function showname () {
      /*var name = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]; 
      console.log(name.files.item(0).name);*/
    var fileName = document.getElementById("fileInput");
    var files = fileName.files;
    var file
    // loop through files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // get item
        file = files.item(i);
        //or
        file = files[i];
        return file.name;
    }
}
```

Todas las demás funciones podían leer `file.Name` ya que obtenían una respuesta directa de la misma función con el `POST`

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var myText = $(".ql-editor").html();
    alert('Guardar');
    var url ="./save";

    $.ajax({
    url: "/save",
    data:{myText : myText, fileName:showname()}, dataType: "POST"
    }).done(function(dat) {
    $(".ql-editor").html(dat)
    })
  });
```

Al final solo tuve que modificar un poco la función ajax, para mandar mediante `/save` el valor `filename:showname()`

```
/* save */
app.get('/save',function(req,res){
    console.log(cData.getData());
    fs.writeFile("./files/"+req.query.fileName, req.query.myText, function (err){
    if (err) return console.log("No funciono");
    console.log('Se ha reescrito perfectamente');
        });
});
```

Y captarlo en el `JS` con el `GET` y el `req.query.fileName`

Ahora lo único malo es que, cualquier texto que escriba, al guardarlo y abrirlo en un .txt, salen las etiquetas de salto de línea, párrafo, etc...Pero ese es otro cantar, de momento me sirve.

**¡¡Muchísimas gracias a los que me habéis ayudado!!**

Comment: Hola, si utilizaras el body podrías guardar la data en un template literal :D, a de mas seria util dejar de utilizar ajax que ya esta un poco deprecated por funcionalidad e ir adoptando nuevas tecnologias y API's como fetch que es estandar o axios que es una libreria, saludos.

Comment: Seguramente sea la forma más eficaz de hacerlo, y te lo agradezco muchísimo, es más, lo probé en un documento a parte y me funcionaba bien, pero a la hora de implementarlo en el código completo que tengo, me era muy raro. Igualmente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo que lo hagas con un método que admita body para poder trabajar con datos mas extensos, el request `get` no recibe body, así que puedes utilizar usar post o put.

En lugar de utilizar queries utiliza parámetros para obtener el `fileName` y el body para obtener el texto, con `body-parser` claro.

**Un ejemplo breve es**:

```
npm i body-parser --save
```

```javascript
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
...
app.post('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
  const { myText } = req.body;
  const { fileName } = req.params
  foo...
})
```

Extenderé mi respuesta cuando indiques en la pregunta como haces el request desde el cliente :D, puede que sea un problema de como armas la url.

**[EDIT]**:

Tampoco entiendo de donde viene `cData.fileName` podrías explicar en donde estas almacenando el `fileName` en ese objeto, probablemente ahí esté el problema.

Realmente lo explicado en el ejemplo es la manera adecuada en la que se debería trabajar para realizar operaciones que requieran guardar o introducir data en el servidor, un saludo.

Comment: Nice, podrias actualizar tu pregunta poniendo como armas la request en el fron-end? y tambien explicando de donde sale `cData.fileName`. Sino como te comenté la manera adecuada de trabajar es con `put` o `post` pero aun así con `get` puedes utilizar los parámetros de url, es mejor que los queries por ejemplo `app.get('/save/:fileName')` y obtienes el parámetro como te explique antes. En el front la request  seria algo como `fetch('/save/myfile.json?myText=foo')`, un saludo.